# Why is Responsive Web design 12 column grid?

Tags: css, responsive-design

Why is Responsive Web design 12 column grid? 
Just Because it's magic number divided by 2, 3, 4, 6 or there is other logic to it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not present a problem that requires a solution.

Comment: Responsive design has nothing to do with a specific grid of some specific size. Responsive design is about being able to adapt to the different resolutions and sizes of the client.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a 12 column grid. Responsive web design is based on the fact that the elements within the page will adapt to different display resolutions. You could have a 2 column grid if you liked.

Comment: "Why is a 12-column grid frequently used in responsive web frameworks such as Twitter Bootstrap and Zurb Foundation" would be a better way to phrase this question.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's magic number divisible by 1, 2, 3, 4, and 6

Answer (score 3):

The fact the `12 column grid` works with devisible numbers untill 1 is the biggest reason it became popular.

Say you want 25% width:

`col-md-4`
vs
`col-md-25`

The second option would require you to make 100 width rules in your CSS, while the first only asks for 12 rules in your CSS. That's not too bad if this is your only width option, but you don't want 100 rules for the columns. That would increase the file size and maintainability.

The `12 column grid` is just some preference of popular frameworks however. The new`Zurb Foundation framework` has the option to change the grid layout with your choice of horizontal elements. I believe, but am not sure, that Bootstrap will give that option with their new TWBS4 framework too, because you can easily alter the SASS implementation by changing a few variables.

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#sass-reference